# CardLayout Button and TextField Size

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, cardlayout

I'm trying to fix the size of the text fields, text area and buttons using `CardLayout`. Currently, they are too big and I want to reduce their size to a more normal size.

So far I have had no luck. My code is below with link to screenshot after the code.

```
public JPanel card3Panel(){
        //JLabel label3 = new JLabel( "card three" );
       
          JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
          card3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
          lSearch = new JLabel("Enter student's name", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
          card3.add(lSearch,BorderLayout.NORTH);
          sSearch = new JTextField(10);
          card3.add(sSearch,BorderLayout.EAST);
          searchButton = new JButton("Submit student search");
          card3.add(searchButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          searchButton.addActionListener(this);
          search = new JTextArea(20,20);
          card3.add(search);
          return card3;
```

ButtonScreenShot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcELL.png]

Comment: What does CardLayout have to do with this question? You're using a GridLayout, but you're adding components using BorderLayout constraints?

Comment: The `CardLayout` has nothing to do with the size of your components. The `CardLayout` just allows you to "swap" panels in the same space of the frame. The reason your buttons are so big is because of the `GridLayout`. The `GridLayout` will take up all the space available and make each component the same size. The code you posted make no sense. You set the layout to `GridLayout`, but then you try to use BorderLayot.NORTH and BorderLayout.SOUTH constraints. Those contraints can only be used on a BorderLayout.

Comment: Read the Swing turtorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples. You can nest panels with different layout manager to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI (one for each card cards) at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) The card layout is only indirectly responsible for the larger size of the buttons & text fields, in that it will make all cards as tall as the tallest and as wide as the widest. There are a number of ways to get each card to retain its preferred size, though.